# delete any record selected but not the current one. c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myConn.Open();
    string query = "Delete * from tbl_attendance where [attendance_id] =" + textBox1.Text + "";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();                      
    string message = "Are you sure you want to delete this data?";
    string caption = "Delete";
    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        cmd.Connection = myConn;
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully deleted recorded data");
        button4.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = true;
        label5.Visible = false;
        textBox1.Visible = false;
        textBox1.Text = "";

        myConn.Close();

        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd2.Connection = myConn;
            string query2 = "Select attendance_id as [ID], username as [Username], time_in as [Time In],time_out as [Time Out] from tbl_attendance";
            cmd.CommandText = query2;

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
        myConn.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        button4.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = true;
        label5.Visible = false;
        textBox1.Visible = false;
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
    myConn.Close();
}
```

I'm not sure what and where to insert a statement, where the last inserted data to may database will not be deleted. Like, any selected record to my datagridview can be deleted, but not the current record, since it is the latest time in recorded. Help please. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you opening and closing the connection so much?

Comment: still making sure everything will run just fine, new to programming. sorry.

Comment: @juharr is right, i suggest you to open the connection after cmd.CommandText = query; and then use the clause finally and use there the myConn.Close();

Comment: not really sure what you mean by 'the current record'?

Comment: Personally I'd create a new connection each time I needed one and I'd do it inside of a `using` statement.  Then you don't have to worry about closing it.

Comment: also parameterise queries

Comment: @Ewan, current record is my time in and every time I time in it is inserted in the last row of my database.

Comment: i suggest you select the max time in for the user on the row you are attempting to delete, then select the row with that user and time in, then compare that row id with the row id you are attempting to delete

Comment: I get the logic but I'm not really sure how to start coding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

caveats :

without your database I cant test this

you code is not structured well, I wont attempt to correct this

you are using access. BAD

im just going to write the selects etc not full code

1: select the row you are trying to delete

```
string id = textBox1.Text;
deleterow  = "Select * from tbl_attendance where id=" + id;
```

2 :get the max time in for the user on the delete row

```
maxtime = "select max(timein) from tbl_attendance where username='" + deleterow["username"] + "'";
```

3: get the row (or rows) for the user and max time in

```
lastrows = "select * from tbl_attendance where username='" +     deleterow["username" + "' and timein='" + maxtimein + "'";
```

4: compare the last rows id with the one you are tryign to delete

```
if (lastrows["id] == id)
{
//dont delete!
}
```